# 'continue' the 'for' loop to the previous element

Tags: python, list, loops, continue

I have been trying to find a way to `continue` my `for` loop to the previous element. It's hard to explain.

Just two be clear, here is an example:

```
foo = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

for bar in foo:
    if bar == "c":
        foo[foo.index(bar)] = "abc"
        continue
    print(bar)
```

On executing this, when the loop reaches to `'c'`, it sees that `bar` is equal to `'c'`, it replaces that `'c'` in the list, `continue`s to the next element & doesn't print `bar`. I want this to loop back to `'b'` after replacing when the `if` condition is true. So it will print `'b'` again and it will be just like the loop never reached `'c'`

<sub>**Background:** I am working on a project. If any error occurs, I have to continue from the previous element to solve this error.</sub>

Here is a flowchart, if it can help:

[image: Flow chart]

I prefer not to modify my existing list except for the replacing I made. I tried searching through every different keyword but didn't found a similar result.

How do I continue the loop to the previous element of the current one?

Comment: Just use a while loop?

Comment: Use a while loop. For loops in python are very different than for loops in other languages. It's actually like a foreach loop.

Comment: Do you want to print a, b, b, abc, d?

Comment: @joumaico Exactly. But note that it is not my main purpose. It is just an example

Comment: As I understood you want to print **a , b ,b , abc, d**? the first *b* is the second element and the second *b* is the element after going back one step and finally *"abc"* is what changed with *"c"* ?

Comment: @Ahmad Yeah. This is the expectation

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami Its also possible in using `for`. Check my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here when the corresponding value of **`i`** is equal to **`c`** the element will change to your request and go back one step, reprinting **`b`** and **`abc`**, and finally **`d`**:

```
foo = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
i = 0
while i < len(foo):
    if foo[i] == "c":
        foo[i] = "abc"
        i -= 1
        continue
    print(foo[i])
    i += 1
```

Comment: I never talked about `while` in my question and all the answers are using `while`.

Comment: you cannot use for because it cannot help you!

Comment: No. I can use `for`. I answered my own question. I knew there must be a way. I am not going to undo acceptance of your answer, but I want you to take a look at it.

Answer (score 4):

In a `for` loop you cannot change the iterator. Use a `while` loop instead:

```
foo = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
i = 0
while i < len(foo):
    if foo[i] == "c":
        foo[foo.index(foo[i])] = "abc"
        i -= 1
        continue
    print(foo[i])
    i += 1
```

Comment: Will break if the first element in the list matches!

Comment: I commend this answer.

Comment: @SamDaniel I agree, but it comes from the defenition of the problem, not from the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to use `for` so I created the code myself. I didn't want to modify my original list so I made a copy of my original list

```
foo = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
foobar = foo.copy()

for bar in foobar:
    if bar == "c":
        foobar[foobar.index(bar)] = "abc"
        foo[foo.index(bar)] = "abc"
        del foobar[foobar.index("abc")+1:]
        foobar += foo[foo.index("abc")-1:]
        continue
    print(bar)
```

It prints as expected:

> ```
> a
> b
> b
> abc
> d
> ```

And my original list also is now:

```
['a', 'b', 'abc', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import collections
left, right = -1,1
foo = collections.deque(["a", "b", "c", "d"])
end = foo[-1]
while foo[0] != end:
    if foo[0] == 'c':
        foo[0] = 'abc'
        foo.rotate(right)
    else:
        print(foo[0])
        foo.rotate(left)
print(foo[0])
```